# Passing two lists as arguments in Haskell

Tags: list, recursion, addition

I'm working on a function which adds elements from two lists one by one. If the result is greater than 10, I just need the least significant digit, not the whole number.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
add (x:xs) (y:ys) = if x+y > 10 then (x+y):add(xs ys)
                     else (x+y-10):add(xs ys)
```

The problem is with the type matching, it gives me errors on recursive calls. It seems like it can't recognize the two lists.

Answer (score 0):

Haskell doesn't require parentheses on function calls. This is a working function call:

```
max 5 2
```

When you put parentheses around the two lists in the add function call, you tell Haskell to interpret them as one object - but just writing two lists behind each other doesn't work in Haskell.

Here's a working variation of your code:

```
add (x:xs) (y:ys) = if x + y > 10 then (x + y - 10):(add xs ys)
                    else (x + y):(add xs ys)
add [] _ = []
add _ [] = []
```

Comment: So this is how it interprets. Makes sense now, thank you